# Injecting a service in Grails PluginDescriptor.groovy file?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to transform/Convert my Grails application into a Grails plugin. This post has been very helpful for me in doing so:
http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1973

While copy pasting the files, and following the above link I am stuck with Bootstrap.groovy file. While I have to paste my Bootstrap.groovy's init() code into ".doWithApplicationContext" , which I have done so, I have a problem regarding injection of sevices. Here is my Application's Bootstrap file:

```
class BootStrap {

    //Injecting voice recordign service
    def processRecordingVoiceRecognizitonService

    //Injecting Service to Connect to AMQ Server to Send Recording 
    def AMQConnectionManagementService

    //Injecting AMQ Publisher to Publish Voice Recognition Results
    def messagePublisherService

    //Injecting AMQ Consumer to Consume Voice Model Creation Notifications
    def messageConsumerService
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

One can see I am injecting Services in my Bootstap.
I have pasted that piece of code at the start of PluginDesciptor.groovy but Intellij Idea is not showing injection sign which means services are not being injected.
Is it actually possible to inject a service in Plugin Descriptor? If not then what is the wok around to initialize and establish necessary connections in the services files?

I have found a related question but couldn't understand. here is the link just in case. [inject service into instance of src/groovy class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343111/inject-service-into-instance-of-src-groovy-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent point to BootStrap in the lifecycle of a plugin descriptor is `doWithApplicationContext`, which receives a reference to the `ApplicationContext` from which you can fetch whatever services you need.  You can't inject services into the descriptor in the normal way because the descriptor is instantiated (and several of its key methods are called) before the `ApplicationContext` has been set up.

```
def doWithApplicationContext = { applicationContext ->
  applicationContext.messagePublisherService.someMethodName()
```

Alternatively, a plugin can provide a bootstrap artefact to applications by naming it something like `MyPluginBootStrap.groovy` - any Groovy class in `grails-app/conf` whose name *ends with* BootStrap will be treated as a bootstrap artefact, it's only the plain `BootStrap.groovy` in the plugin that is excluded from being "contributed" to applications that depend on the plugin.

Comment: So just changing the the name of Bootstrap.goovy will work? Everything will act as it supposed to be? And Services can also be normally injected in that file? If yes, then how strange solution!

Comment: Can I use the same thing for Config.groovy aswell? If I change the name to MyPluginConfig.groovy, and add all the configurations in it, will they work?

Comment: @MasoodFarooqMalik yes, you can simply rename BootStrap to AnythingBootStrap.  But no, the same thing does not work for Config, that is the sole responsibility of the host application.  Some plugins like spring-security-core use tricks to inject a default configuration via `doWithSpring` but there's no standard mechanism.

Comment: @MasoodFarooqMalik it's no different from any other Java or Groovy class - the class name should match the file name so if it's `Anything_BootStrap.groovy` then it needs to contain `class Anything_BootStrap`